# Converting an existing Azure VM to a Reserved Instance

Tags: azure, reserved-instances

I have a long running VM on Azure.  I recently read about Reserved Instances.

Is it possible to convert/transfer/ move my existing VM to a reserved instance, or do I need to build a new VM from Scratch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you have to do is to go to Azure Portal >> Navigate to All Services >> Reservations >> Click Add >> Define a scope and create.

You don't assign that reservation to specific VM, the discount is applied at the subscription level (or shared subscription level) automatically. See here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-vm-reservation-charges

And here's how you pay for it:

> For Enterprise Agreement (EA) customers, Azure Monetary Commitment can
>   be used to purchase Azure Reserved VM Instances. In scenarios where EA
>   customers have used all of their monetary commitment, RIs can still be
>   purchased, and those purchases will be invoiced on their next overage
>   bill.
>
> For customers purchasing via Azure.com, at the time of purchase, the
>   credit card on file will be charged for the full upfront payment of
>   the Azure Reserved Instances.